# After workflow, column has to be updated

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there any feasibilty to update a list column value after an approval flow is done?

I have created a workflow which is approval workflow. After that I want to update the column.

Comment: Hi Robert, Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which column you are referring to, you can do this in your workflow.

If it the workflow list column you can update it by using the workflow action: Set Workflow Status

If it is any other column you can do it through the workflow action: Update list item

Comment: Hi I wrote approval workflow now client want to add the new column as Status in that user need to edit the list as progress or completed.How can i do that.I tried it but it is affecting previous workflow.If i edit the list Approved mode is changing to Pending mode again.What can i do for this?

Comment: Can you specify how many workflows you have running on your list? And which columns you are updating through your workflows?

Comment: I am running one workflow in the list.After workflow is done user need to update the list as "Completed" in the same list.If i editing the list for updating the status to "Completed" after workflow done it is going back to pending state.

Comment: If the workflow starts when the item is modified, then you need to insert a check in the beginning of that workflow, so it will only run when the status is not equal to 'Completed'.

Assuming that the workflow is setting the status to pending.